# ClientId is different in localhost and the webserver

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I am facing a new kind of problem.

I am using the jQuery to fill the state dropdown on the change of country dropdown and the code of the jquery is on a js file so i bind the static client id like ct100_ddlCountry, this is working properly on the localhost but when i host this website to web server it not working because the client generating on the server is _ct100_ddlCountry.

Please tell me something if anyone has an idea about this.  I am new to this kind of problem.

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't upgrade to .NET 4.0 for clean id's, I wrote a small lib and shoved it on CodePlex to serialize controls to a JSON array on the client.

http://awesomeclientid.codeplex.com/

http://www.philliphaydon.com/2010/12/i-love-clean-client-ids-especially-with-net-2-0/

It serializes the controls and outputs some JavaScript like:

```
<script type=”text/javascript”>
//<![CDATA[
var controls = {
"txtUserName": "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtUserName",
"txtEmail": "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtEmail",
"btnSubmit": "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnSubmit"
};
//]]>
</script>
```

Which then allows you to access controls like:

```
<script type=”text/javascript”>
//<![CDATA[
var element = document.getElementById(controls.btnSubmit);
//]]>
</script>
```

No need to write spaghetti code :)

Edit: Alternatively, you can use jQuery selectors to do something like:

`var control = $('[id*=txtEmail]');`

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy, its new and also interesting .

Comment: No problem, if you have any questions or need help you can contact me via my blog.

Answer (score 1):

It is not normally good practice to hard code control ids in your js script includes or html source.

Try using something like this:

JS

```
function DoChange(controlid) {
    $("#"+controlid);
}
```

HTML

```
<select onchange='DoChange("<%= ddlCountry.ClientID %>");' />
```

It means if you move your control around in your control tree, then you dont break your code, and it should work on your localhost and IIS

**UPDATE**

Or like this

JS

```
function DoChange(control) {
    $(control);
}
```

HTML

```
<select onchange="DoChange(this);" />
```

Comment: Sometime I have noticed that if <%= somecontrol.ClientID %> is giving quite big control id then jQuery gets confused and refuses to pick up the element.

Answer (score 0):

If it is ASP.Net 4.0 then you can use `ClientIDMode="Static"` to make sure that only IDs provided by you are there on final markup.

Or you can use something like `$('id$=country')`. $ is used to match the end of Id, but I am sure that is something not optimal.